# Geany-indent multiple lines at the same time

Tags: geany

In Geany, is it possible to indent multiple lines at the same time using a keyboard shortcut (instead of typing every indent by hand)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maybe I did not understand the question correctly, but both the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key and the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> shortcut do exactly that when multiple lines are selected.

For unindenting multiple lines, you can use both the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> shortcuts.

Generally, (<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+)<kbd>TAB</kbd> seems to work in 95% of all modern text editors. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>/<kbd>u</kbd> is more Geany-specific, but can easily be found in the Geany Settings (Settings -> Keybindings -> Format).